# Specialization of a class template method, with typenames that are class template - error: type/value mismatch at argument

Tags: c++, class, templates, template-specialization

My question is, do I have to specify the "type" of template, when it is a parameter of another template? This in a specialization of a method.

Let me permit put you in the context.

I'm doing a TicTacToe game, in which there is a template Computer class. So, I can set the difficulty level of it in the parameters.
This is a sample of it:

```
template<int T>
class Computer
{
    Node *Root;         /**< Root of a decision tree */
    Node *Current;      /**< Current node in a decision tree*/

    int PlayerNumber;   /**< Player ID*/
    int OponnentNumber  /**< Opponent ID*/

  Public:

    /**< Constructor destructor */
    int refreshBoard(int move);
    int play()const; /**< This methods has different implementations, for each level of difficulty*/
}
```

Then, I came up with an idea to create a tempated TicTacToe class, so the parameters receives different types of players.
This is a sample.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class TicTacToe
{
    T1 &Player1;        /**< Simulates the first player */
    T2 &Player2;        /**< Simulates the second player */

     Board &b__;        /**< Simulates a board */

     int TurnCounter; 
 public:
    int newTurn(); 
 /* This method is implemented differently for each type of combination of player
  * Lets say player 1 is Human and player 2 is computer. The new turn will 
  * change the state of the board and will return 1 if there is still new turns 
  * to come.
  */
}
```

**Returning to my question:** I'm having problems in setting the correct grammar, so the compiler understand me.

It returns lots of erros:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template<class T1, class T2> class TicTacToe’
 int JogoVelha<Human,Computer>::newTurn()`


note: expected a type, got ‘Computer’
header/TicTacToe.h:201:40: error: ‘newTurn’ is not a template function
 int TicTacToe<Human,Computer>::newTurn()
```

For this type of organization

```
template<>
int TicTacToe<Human,Computer>::newTurn() 
...implementation
```

And I cannot understand why. I need your help.

Comment: I assume this is just for experimentation purposes? Because otherwise I don't really see the advantage of using templates here over just using a Player interface that is implemented by HumanPlayer and ComputerPlayer classes...

Comment: It was a project decision when I started. Latter on I noticed it wasn't the greatest choice. However, your idea did not came in my mind and it is much direct and simpler, then what I came up with. If you don't mind, I will be using what you said, to build upon my Battleship project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Computer` is a class template, you have to specify the template argument when using it, e.g.

```
template<>
int TicTacToe<Human,  Computer<42>>::newTurn()
```

Or you can [partial specify](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) `TicTacToe` for the class template like `Computer` which takes an `int` template parameter. .e.g

```
template <typename T1, template <int> class T2, int I>
class TicTacToe<T1, T2<I>>

{
    T1 &Player1;        
    T2<I> &Player2;
    ...
};
```

then use it like

```
TicTacToe<int, Computer<42>> t;
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/XFNSGI91585)

Comment: So, the first suggestion will force me to make 20 types of specialization, if there were 20 types of difficulty levels, although the implementation perspective in the TicTacToe class  is the same? Isn't there an option like a void pointer or something more generic?

Comment: @Homunculus Answer revised.